# 2D Array with random values, but the values in two of the columns should not be the same

Tags: java, arrays, random

I have this number generator, which generates me a 2d matrix with random values. The values in column 4 and 5 are either 1, 3, 7 or 20. But when column 4 is a 1, column 5 should be either 3, 7 or 20 (they should never have the same values).

I tried it with the double x and double y declaration under the second for-loop, but that doesn't work. So in my next try, I would try it with a do-while-loop, but I don't know, how to implement that loop in my code.

```
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Number[][] values = new Number[10][26];
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
                double x = Math.random();
                double y = x < 0.25 ? 1 : x < 0.5 ? 0.74 : x < 0.75 ? 0.49 : 0.01;
                if (j == 0) {
                    values[i][j] = Math.random() < 0.5 ? 0 : 1;
                  } else if (j == 1) {
                    values[i][j] = (int)Math.floor(((Math.random() * (250000000 - 500000)) + 500000));
                  } else if (j == 2) {
                    values[i][j] = (int)(Math.random() * (23)) + 1;
                  } else if (j == 3) {
                    values[i][j] = x < 0.25 ? 1 : x < 0.5 ? 3 : x < 0.75 ? 7 : 20; 
                  } else if (j == 4) {
                    values[i][j] = y < 0.25 ? 1 : y < 0.5 ? 3 : y < 0.75 ? 7 : 20;
                  } else {
                    values[i][j] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000) / 100000; 
                  }
                System.out.print(values[i][j] + " ; ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "that doesn't work". Are you getting some errors? If so, add them to the question.

Comment: "That doesn't work" is not a proper description of your problem.

Comment: Btw. You need to come up with a different algorithm for generating those numbers. At the moment Y depends on the value of X, eg. if one column is 3 then the other will always be 7 (just example values), thats not really random.

Comment: sorry for this statement. i don't get any errors, it just doesn't go as it should

Comment: Then you should describe what it does and why it doesn't fulfil your requirements.

Comment: the values in columns 4 and 5 can still be the same (and I don't want that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably many different ways of achieving the same result. The solution I came up with looks like so:

- Declare a list of all possible ints for a given row - outside of the inner loop
- For columns 3 or 4 get a random index from range 0 - sizeOfList
- Take element with that index from the List and assign to your matrix
- Remove element with that index from the List so it isn't reused later on

Note that I used `Random.nextInt(sizeOfList)` here, it's just cleaner than `Math.random()`.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Number[][] values = new Number[10][26];
       Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

            List<Integer> possibleInts = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 3, 7, 20));

            for (int j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
                if (j == 0) {
                    values[i][j] = Math.random() < 0.5 ? 0 : 1;
                  } else if (j == 1) {
                    values[i][j] = (int)Math.floor(((Math.random() * (250000000 - 500000)) + 500000));
                  } else if (j == 2) {
                    values[i][j] = (int)(Math.random() * (23)) + 1;
                  } else if (j == 3) {

                    int index = r.nextInt(possibleInts.size());  
                    values[i][j] = possibleInts.get(index);
                    possibleInts.remove(index);

                  } else if (j == 4) {

                    int index = r.nextInt(possibleInts.size());  
                    values[i][j] = possibleInts.get(index);
                    possibleInts.remove(index);

                  } else {
                    values[i][j] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000) / 100000; 
                  }
                System.out.print(values[i][j] + " ; ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```